# Use String.contains in an Apex page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

```
<apex:outputField rendered="{!(WidgetType.contains('mywidget1'))}" />
```

When I do this I get an error...

> Error: Unknown function WidgetType.contains. Check spelling

... even though the WidgetType returns a String!

It will let me do this though...

> rendered="{!(WidgetType == 'mywidget1')}"

Here is the property in the controller...

```
public String getWidgetType() {
    return Settings.getWidgetType();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the `CONTAINS` function [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) (pasted below).

---

***Description***

Compares two arguments of text and returns TRUE if the first argument contains the second argument. If not, returns FALSE.

The following example checks the content of a custom text field named Product_Type and returns “Parts” for any product with the word “part” in it. Otherwise, it returns “Service.”
`{!IF(contains(opportunity.Product_Type__c, "part"), "Parts", "Service")}`

This function is case sensitive so be sure your compare_text value has the correct capitalization.

***Use***

`CONTAINS(text, compare_text)` and replace text with the text that contains the value of compare_text.

---

In your case, you would need to use it like this:

```
<apex:outputField rendered="{!(CONTAINS(WidgetType,'mywidget1'))}" />
```

Comment: That's right. You cannot use APEX methods (user defined or otherwise) in a VF page, but you can use functions (those available for formula fields).

Comment: Also, if you ever want to call an Apex method from JavaScript, use apex:actionFunction.

Comment: Or [JavaScript Remoting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm). :)

Comment: If you're concerned with case sensitivity issues, you'll need to use the functions LOWER or UPPER to ensure the proper text comparison occurs.

Comment: For your case this would look like: rendered="{!(CONTAINS(LOWER(WidgetType),'mywidget1'))}"

Answer (score 0):

`<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(contains('long_string','short_string_to_check'))}" />`

This works for me.